# Apache 403 error forbidden localhost

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I'm just trying to set up localhost so it points to this directory on my machine:

```
/home/mdobrenko/Sites
```

I created a new conf file (app.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.66
    ServerName localhost.dev
DocumentRoot /home/mdobrenko/Sites
<Directory /home/mdobrenko/Sites>
    # Don't show directory index
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

    # Allow .htaccess files
    AllowOverride All

    # Allow web access to this directory
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Error and access logs
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.error.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.access.log combined
```

When I try to access localhost.dev, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I am able to access localhost just fine, though.

I'm a total newbie to Linux and Web Administration - any help is appreciated, I'm sure it's a silly mistake I made somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Directory /home/mdobrenko/Sites>
# Don't show directory index
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

    # Allow .htaccess files
    AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Seems like I still get the same error -- any other ideas?

Comment: yep -- sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/413887/403-forbidden-after-changing-documentroot-directory-apache-2-4-6

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.